# Linux on M1 Mac install java, error: Java:cannot execute binary file

Tags: java, linux, java-8, apple-m1

In the virtual machine, after I installed jdk1.8 and configured the environment variables, I tried typing "java" to make sure jdk was configured successfully. But it reported an error:
"-bash: /opt/module/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java: **cannot execute binary file**"

[Run java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzlPQ.png)

WHY？？？

I'm sure all the software I use is arm architecture, otherwise I wouldn't be able to start Linux. And the JDK is 64-bit.

I created my own environment variable configuration file under "profile.d". Here's what's inside that file.

```
#JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/module/jdk1.8.0_212
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

| PC | MacBook Air M1 |
| --- | --- |
| Virtual Machine | VMware Fusion |
| Linux | CentOS 7 ARM |
| JDK | jdk1.8.0_212 |

Comment: What is the output of `file /opt/module/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java`?

Comment: # file java

java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: What's the output of ```$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version``` ?

Comment: `x86-64` is not an ARM compatible binary, it is compiled for Intel/AMD. It would say something like : `arm64e` if it was an ARM binary.

Comment: Thanks! I found another JDK adapted to arm and the problem is solved

Comment: @EZSun Hi. Since you solved the problem yourself, you should answer your own question and then accept the answer. That way, other people with the same problem  can find the answer here.